# Let $\{A_α\}$ be a collection of connected subspaces of $X$; let A be con. sub. of X. Show that if $A∩A_α≠ ∅$ $∀α$, then $A∪(∪ A_α)$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\{A_\alpha\}$ be a collection of connected subspaces of $X$; let
>    $A$ be connectted subspace of $X$. Show that if $A\cap A_\alpha \neq
>  \emptyset$ for all $\alpha$, then $A\cup(\cup A_\alpha)$ is connected.

I know this theorem:[image]

And as every set in this union has a point in common with $A$, I guess I need to use this. If $\{U_\alpha \}$ was countable I could easily use this theorem with induction, but now I'm not sure if I can use such an argument.

I mean $A\cup A_1$ is connected, therefore $A\cup A_1 \cup A_2$ connected and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A \cup A_{\alpha}$ is connected for all $\alpha$ and therefore $A \cup (\bigcup A_{\alpha}) = \bigcup (A \cup A_{\alpha})$ is connected by your theorem because it is the union of connected sets that have $A$ in common.

Comment: Theorem 23.3 applies to subspaces that have a point in common, whereas the problem only guarantees that these subspaces intersect a common subspace.

Answer (score 3):

If you assume that $A\cup(\cup A_{\alpha})$ is disconnected. Therefor it can be written as the union of two disjoint non-empty closed subsets $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$. But because $A\cap A_{\alpha}\neq \emptyset$  for all $\alpha$ you get $A\cap U_{1}\neq \emptyset$ and $A\cap U_{2}\neq \emptyset$. But this would mean that $A$ is disconnected, this is a contradiction with the assumption that $A$ is connected .